# Creating a short unique ID based on other values in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, uniqueidentifier

I have a number of variables in python that I want to use to generate a unique ID for those variables (yet have that ID always produce for those same matching variables).

I have used `.encode('hex','strict')` to produce an ID which *seems* to work, however the output value is very long.  Is there a way to produce a *shorter* ID using variables?

```
myname = 'Midavalo'
mydate = '5 July 2017'
mytime = '8:19am'

codec = 'hex'

print "{}{}{}".format(myname, mydate, mytime).encode(codec,'strict')
```

This outputs

```
4d69646176616c6f35204a756c792032303137383a3139616d
```

I realise with `hex` it is probably dependant on the length of the three variables, so I'm wondering if there is another codec that can/will produce shorter values without excluding any of the variables?

So far I have tested `base64`, `bz2`, `hex`, `quopri`, `uu`, `zip` from [7.8.4. Python Specific Encodings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings), but I'm unsure how to get any of these to produce shorter values without removing variables.

Is there another codec I could use, or a way to shorten the values from any of them without removing the uniqueness, or even a completely different way to produce what I require?

All I am trying to do is produce an ID so I can identify those rows when loading them into a database.  If the same value already exists it will not create a new row in the database.  There is no security requirement, just a unique ID.  The values are generated elsewhere into python, so I can't just use a database issued ID for these values.

Comment: You definitely don't need 17 (or more) bytes to represent a timestamp (let alone only with a 1 minute resolution).

Comment: Don't know if it would be short enough, but having a similar problem I just converted the date in `YYYYMMDDHHmmss` format (in your example `20170705081900`) and concatenate `_Name`. It would surely be shorter than your triel. If you want to shorten it further remove the first 2 characters from the year and the seconds. It has the advantage of being human readable (I bet it's got tons of disatvantages that I can't think or don't know about)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use some hashing algorithm from the hashlib package: https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html or for python 2: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/hashlib.html

```
import hashlib
s = "some string"
hash = hashlib.sha1(str.encode(s)).hexdigest() # you need to encode the strings into bytes here
```

This hash would be the same for the same string.
Your choice of algorithm depends of the number of chars you want and the risk of collision(two different strings yielding the same hash).

Answer (score 0):

If you are not specific to hash and just want a uniq value based on the two or more strings. It concatenates the first character of every string and outputs a uniq value

```
#prints HKRC1LB for two string1 and string2

#Concatenate first char of all strings to get a uniq id
def get_uniq_val(*args):
    id = ""
    for i in args:
        for j in i.split():
            id += j[0]         
    return id

def main():
    string_1 = "Howard Kid Recreation Centre"
    string_2 = "150 Lantern Blvd"

    uid = get_uniq_val(string_1,string_2)
    print(uid) 
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```